# Set left and right limit ranges simultaneously for dual y-axis plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a dataframe `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2022-4-30", "2022-5-5", "2022-5-6", 
"2022-5-9", "2022-5-10", "2022-5-11", "2022-5-12", "2022-5-13", 
"2022-5-16", "2022-5-17", "2022-5-18", "2022-5-19", "2022-5-20"
), value1 = c(6, 6.1, 6.5, 6.9, 7.3, 7.7, 8.1, 8, 7.9, 7.8, 7.7, 
7.6, 7.5), value2 = c(-1L, -2L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 18L, 
16L, 12L, 19L, 20L), value3 = c(2.7, 2.4, 1.7, 0.5, -0.5, 0.2, 
-0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 1.3, 1.1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Out:

```
        date value1 value2 value3
1  2022-4-30    6.0     -1    2.7
2   2022-5-5    6.1     -2    2.4
3   2022-5-6    6.5      0    1.7
4   2022-5-9    6.9      6    0.5
5  2022-5-10    7.3      7   -0.5
6  2022-5-11    7.7      5    0.2
7  2022-5-12    8.1      3   -0.3
8  2022-5-13    8.0     10   -0.2
9  2022-5-16    7.9     18    0.4
10 2022-5-17    7.8     16    0.9
11 2022-5-18    7.7     12    1.3
12 2022-5-19    7.6     19    1.1
13 2022-5-20    7.5     20    1.0
```

I use code below to plot dual y-axis (left side for `value1` and `value3`, right side for `value2`):

```
df_m <- melt(df, id.vars = 'date')
df_m <- df_m %>% 
  mutate(date=as.Date(date))

df_m1 <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("value1", 'value3')) 

df_m2 <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("value2")) %>%
  mutate(value = value * 0.6)


df_m2
coeff = 1/0.6

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df_m1[!is.na(df_m1$value), ], aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), alpha = 1, size = 1) +
  geom_line(data = df_m2[!is.na(df_m2$value), ], aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), alpha = 1, size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = '',
    # limits=c(-1, 9),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = ""))
```

Out:

[image]

Now I wondering if it's possible to set `limits=c(-1, 9)` for **left y-axis** and `limits=c(-2, 20)` for **right y-axis** simultaneously using ggplot2?

I try with code below, but right y-axis's changed to around `limits=c(-2, 15)`, not as figure above. Alternative solutions to plot a similar dual y-axis plot will be welcomed as well.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df_m1[!is.na(df_m1$value), ], aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), alpha = 1, size = 1) +
  geom_line(data = df_m2[!is.na(df_m2$value), ], aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), alpha = 1, size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = '',
    limits=c(-1, 9),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = ""))
```

[image]

Reference：

https://r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html

Comment: Axis limiting is on the primary axis only. You can use `coeff` to derive the numbers you need, `c(-2,20)/coeff` is a start, though it is not clear with `c(-1.2,12)` how you would always expect to deal with the different ranges. Perhaps `c(min(-1, -2/coeff), max(9, 20/coeff))`?

Comment: I tested with `limits =c(min(-1, -2/coeff), max(9, 20/coeff))`, it seems generating same as without setting limits for this case.

Comment: Okay, try `max` and `min` (swapped) instead. Which to choose is up to you, the premise of my comment is that ggplot does not support very many things based on a second axis, limiting is not supported. Even if it did, there is ambiguity in what it should do based on the ambiguity of the immediate request? If the limits on the primary axis are more restrictive than on the secondary axis, should it expand to include both or choose the more restrictive? I think it's easy enough to calculate them yourself using your preference for expansion/contraction.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insights, as far as I know, ggplot doesn't encourage user drawing dual y-axis plot, @teunbrand's ggh4x package solved this  particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons `ggh4x::help_secondary()` was written. Essentially it figures out the transformation needed to get the secondary range to match the primary range and the inverse. We apply the transformation to secondary data and it's inverse is used as the `trans` argument of the secondary axis.

In your example, we can drop the `mutate()` bit, because that is handled in `sec$proj()`.

(Disclaimer: I wrote ggh4x)

```r
# df <- structure(...) # omitted for brevity

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df_m <- melt(df, id.vars = 'date')
df_m <- df_m %>% 
  mutate(date=as.Date(date))

df_m1 <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("value1", 'value3')) 

df_m2 <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("value2"))

sec <- ggh4x::help_secondary(
  name = "",
  primary = c(-1, 9), secondary = c(-2, 20),
)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df_m1[!is.na(df_m1$value), ], 
            aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), alpha = 1, size = 1) +
  geom_line(data = df_m2[!is.na(df_m2$value), ], 
            aes(x = date, y = sec$proj(value), col = variable), alpha = 1, size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-1, 9),
    name = '',
    sec.axis = sec)
```

[image]

Comment: Great package solved this issue perfectly, thanks for sharing!!!